# Issue combining 2 separate sets | Swift

Tags: swift

I currently have 2 sets `recordSet` that is a simple string set and `issueSet`  that is based on the struct `selectedIssuesStruct`

```
var recordSet:Set<String>

issueSet: Set<selectedIssuesStruct> = []

struct selectedIssuesStruct : Codable, Hashable {
    var name: String
    var id: Int
}
```

**I am working with both sets at the following state when they look like this:**

```
recordSet: ["Jake", "Mary", "Tim"]

issueSet: [
myApp.selectedIssuesStruct(name: "", id: 4), 
myApp.selectedIssuesStruct(name: "", id: 3), 
myApp.selectedIssuesStruct(name: "", id: 2)
]
```

**Note:** name is meant to be blank at this point, when id is populated name is not passed, resulting in an empty string. How can I populate each name from record set into issueSet as many times there are issues? To avoid confusion, please see the result I am trying to get to.

**Result I am trying to get to:**

```
issueSet: [
myApp.selectedIssuesStruct(name: "Jake", id: 4), 
myApp.selectedIssuesStruct(name: "Jake", id: 3), 
myApp.selectedIssuesStruct(name: "Jake", id: 2),
myApp.selectedIssuesStruct(name: "Mary", id: 4), 
myApp.selectedIssuesStruct(name: "Mary", id: 3), 
myApp.selectedIssuesStruct(name: "Mary", id: 2),
myApp.selectedIssuesStruct(name: "Tim", id: 4), 
myApp.selectedIssuesStruct(name: "Tim", id: 3), 
myApp.selectedIssuesStruct(name: "Tim", id: 2)
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over `recordSet` using `flatMap` -- this will `map` over each element letting you return an array that will then be flattened at the end of the process into a single dimensional array (not a 2-dimensional array as you would get if you just used `map`).

Within the `flatMap`, you can create a `SelectedIssuesStruct` that takes the `name` from the `recordSet` and pairs it with the `id`s from the `issueSet`

```
struct SelectedIssuesStruct : Codable, Hashable {
    var name: String
    var id: Int
}

let recordSet:Set<String> = ["Jake", "Mary", "Tim"]

let issueSet: Set<SelectedIssuesStruct> = [
    SelectedIssuesStruct(name: "", id: 4),
    SelectedIssuesStruct(name: "", id: 3),
    SelectedIssuesStruct(name: "", id: 2)
]

let result = recordSet.flatMap { name in
    issueSet.map { issue in
        SelectedIssuesStruct(name: name, id: issue.id)
    }
}
print(result)
```

This yields the following (remember that `Set` is unordered):

> [SelectedIssuesStruct(name: "Tim", id: 4),
> SelectedIssuesStruct(name: "Tim", id: 3),
> SelectedIssuesStruct(name: "Tim", id: 2),
> SelectedIssuesStruct(name: "Jake", id: 4),
> SelectedIssuesStruct(name: "Jake", id: 3),
> SelectedIssuesStruct(name: "Jake", id: 2),
> SelectedIssuesStruct(name: "Mary", id: 4),
> SelectedIssuesStruct(name: "Mary", id: 3),
> SelectedIssuesStruct(name: "Mary", id: 2)]

*Note that I've changed `selectedIssuesStruct` to `SelectedIssuesStruct` to follow the Swift naming conventions*